# Changing colour of all fullstops (periods) on site

Tags: html, jquery, css

A bit of a random request, but we are looking to change all the fullstop colours on the site to be green.

We are trying to wrap all fullstops in a span, but having no luck. I would imagine this is the best route around it? What we have tried so far is:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col txt-col aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-right">
            <h2 class="">Test</h2>
            <h4>Test content.</h4>
            <p>Testing 1 2 3.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col image-col aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="250">
            <p>Testing.</p>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>

$('.container').each(function () {
     $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/./g, '<span class="fs-color">.</span>'));
});
```

But unfortunately this is targeting the entire string.

Would anyone have any advise?

Thank you

Comment: @Brad [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/zogolarene/edit?html,css,js,output) - it works for me. (I made the background red because the colour of dots is hard to see).

Comment: I haven noticed this is removing the . within the image HTML and breaking the image. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, believe I have now found the answer with this:-

```
$('p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function () {
     $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\./g, '<span class="fs-color">.</span>'));
});
```